# Access to openvpn client LAN from openvpn server

Tags: openvpn

My setup looks like that:

```
 --------------------------------      ---------------------------------
|Digital Ocean droplet          |      |TC7200 router                  |
|Running OpenVPN server         | <--> |                               |
|                               |      |LAN: 192.168.0.1               |
|OpenVPN IP: 10.8.0.1           |      |WAN: 78.11.146.13              |
 --------------------------------      ---------------------------------

                                                    ^
                                                    |
                                                    V
                                        -------------------------------
                                        | RaspberryPi+OpenVPN client  | 
                                        | LAN: 192.168.0.28           |
                                        | tun0: 10.8.0.6              |
                                        -------------------------------
                                                    ^
                                                    |
                                                    V
                                        -------------------------------
                                        | Android phone with IP Webcam| 
                                        | LAN: 192.168.0.39           |
                                        -------------------------------
```

What I want to achieve is to access from openvpn server (10.8.0.1) to IP WebCam (192.168.0.39).

server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir ccd
route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 67.207.67.2"
push "dhcp-option DNS 67.207.67.3"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

ccd/client

```
iroute 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
push route "192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

route:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         159.89.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
159.89.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

With this configuration I'm able to connect from openvpn server to raspbery pi using ssh. I'm able to connect(ssh) or ping from another vpn client to raspberry pi. But I don't know how to configure openvpn server to get access to raspberry pi LAN devices. Maybe I should forward some ports on my home router?